# Android SSL internals - where is the actual implementation?

Tags: android, ssl, implementation, android-source

I've downloaded the source code for the entire Android platform and I'm interested in looking at the SSL implementation. For example, when visiting an SSL enabled site, I'd like to figure out exactly how Android does the SSL hand shake and sets up the connection.

I've looked through various sections of the code but I haven't found what I'm looking for yet so I thought I'd ask here and see if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you planning on documenting what you find out? I'm interested too.

Comment: Did you find the `SSLEngine` or other classes' implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web browser application source code is at:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Browser

Most of the functionality would be in android.webkit.WebView and related classes:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/webkit

Some of this package is implemented in C++. Again though, most of the functionality would be implemented by WebKit (which is written in C++):

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/webkit

I think WebKit uses curl:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/webkit/+/gingerbread-release/WebCore/platform/network

And curl uses OpenSSL:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/openssl

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but the SSL in Android is provided by openssl.  The code for this library can be found in `/androidroot/external/openssl`

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how the SSL handshake works - which parts happen in Java and which parts are handled by the OpenSSL library? Where and how is the secret key generated? That sort of thing...